# Bind text changed event to text area in editor template in Kendo Grid - MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

[image]The following is my html on my view. 
I have the following on my html 1)Text Box (for user to enter key words) 2)Apply Button :which on click gets the text typed inside the text box and other filters (which is not shown) here, makes an ajax call to bind data to the grid as shown.

My problem :
On the kendo grid , one of my column is a template column as shown below. The editor template is defined for that column as seen below.Am trying to suggest to the user "suggestions/suggested tags" as and when he/she types inside the text area (which is inside the grid).
for e.g.when the user types say A;B;C as when a semicolon is entered I would like to suggest tags for;in this case "A" and then "B" and so on.. In order to get this done I would like to add a text changed event-like event to the text area in editor template. Is it possible? If so may i know how to go about it?

```
       <input type="text" id="tb_Search" />
       <input type="button" value="Apply" style="width: 140px" onclick="ApplyFiltersToFetch()" />

       @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CurationModuleV3.Models.Model1>()
                    .Name("TGrid").Pageable
                     ().EnableCustomBinding(true)
                    .DataSource(dataSource =>
                    {
                        dataSource.Ajax()
                        .Update(update => update.Action("RefreshGrid", "Home"))
                        .PageSize(10)
                          .Model(model =>
                          {
                              model.Id(t =>t.UserID);
                          }
                     ).Batch(true).ServerOperation(false);
                    })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(t => t.UserID).Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(t => t.Tags).Title("Tags").EditorTemplateName("TagColumnTemplate").ClientTemplate("<pre name='Tags' id='#=UserID#' style='height: 60px;overflow: auto;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;'>#= Tags#</pre>").Width(180).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "padding:0;top:0;" });
                    }).ToolBar(toolbar =>
                    {
                        toolbar.Save().SaveText("Save all changes");
                    })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:450px;" }).Scrollable().Sortable().ClientDetailTemplateId("templateForInnerUserGrid"))
    <script>
    function ApplyFiltersToFetch() {
    var searchTextValue;
    var grid = $('#TGrid').data("kendoGrid");
     searchTextValue = document.getElementById("tb_Search").value;
     if (!(searchTextValue == "")){ $('#TGrid').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("FetchT", "Home")',
            data: { searchText: searchTextValue},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                grid.dataSource.data(result);
                grid.refresh();
                grid.dataSource.page(1);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });}
       </script>

      /*****Editor Template*********/
      @model string
      @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t, new {rows = 4, wrap = "hard",style = "text-overflow:ellipsis; display:block; width:94%; height:100%;font-family:Segoe UI , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;font-size: 0.85em;" }
                       )
```

EDIT:
May be i was not clear enough. Am not trying to bind any event for my search text box here. I just had my code to show how I bind my data to my grid. I do not want en event for my search text box, however I would like to have an event handler binded to my text area inside the grid (that shows up on edit). On typing inside my grid I would like to suggest to users tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matt, for providing me the start. Hence I included the class name in the editor template as seen below

```
@model string
@Html.TextAreaFor(t => t, new {rows = 4,*@class="tagColEdit"*,wrap = "hard",style = "text-overflow:ellipsis; display:block; width:94%; height:100%;font-family:Segoe UI , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;font-size: 0.85em;"}
```

)

then I added the event handler as suggested by Matt

```
$(function () {
    $('#TGrid').on('keypress', '.tagColEdit', function () {
        alert('Hello');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add the type to the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

then change your function to

```
$('#tb_Search').on('keyup', function(){
    //put the function here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what am looking for, kindly see my edit.My search text box there is just a filter to bind data to the grid, I would like to know how to add an event to the text area that shows up inside my grid on edit.

Comment: this event can be tied to any field you want.  just change the selector (# for id, . for class).  I am not sure how you want to show the suggestions to the user.  I was suggesting you put the ajax call in my click event that will call the controller where you can return results based on what they have typed.  If there is another way you want to do it, let me know and ill try to help

Comment: Thank you Matt, I really appreciate your input, and as per that I tried doing the following @model string
@Html.TextAreaFor(t => t, 
new 
{rows = 4,@class="test1",wrap = "hard",style = "text-overflow:ellipsis; display:block; width:94%; height:100%;font-family:Segoe UI , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;font-size: 0.85em;"}
) and adding the following handler $(function () {
        $('#TGrid').on('change', '.test1', function () {
             alert('Hello');
        })
    }) however this event is hit on out of focus and not on type..Am i missing something?

Comment: change will fire when focus is lost,  keyup will fire when the typed key is released

Comment: Yes, you are right, keypress or keydown does the trick. Thank you, will post the complete answer here.